# can I compile my own PHP while keeping the one provided with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I want to both keep the latest PHP provided with Ubuntu and to have a specific PHP version installed somewhere. Is it doable? Can I just compile the PHP in some folder and then somewhere in Apache configs (I mean the apache provided with Ubuntu) switch between PHP dirs when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Fisrt compile & install new php, and then define your new php as a cgi module to apache.
open apache config file and add this lines

```
<Directory /your/desired/directory/>
        AddHandler my-php-script .php
        Action my-php-script /path/to/your/php_executable
</Directory>
```

or you may system wide define new extension

```
AddHandler my-php-script .myphp
Action my-php-script /path/to/your/php_executable
```