# Installing php5 package with Ubuntu - which PHP version?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have a Ubuntu server running apache2 and have installed php5 with

```
apt-get install php5 php-pear
```

and some other packages packages; `php5-mysql`, for example.

I'm a little confused as to which version of PHP the Ubuntu php5 package ships with. I'd like to be running the latest version of PHP at all times (currently 5.4.15). If I compile PHP from source on my server would that cause issues updating down the line? What's the best option here? Also, any tutorials for how to compile PHP, as I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing! But I'd like to give it a go.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 raring.

I'm new to sysadmin and server management, so it's more than likely I've missed a key piece of the puzzle here.

Any help greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install php5` installs  php version 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2
you can check your php version with `php -v`

running whatever ships with the repository is normally fine for me, exceptions to this would be if there are severe or critical security holes found in php or there is a new feature that you MUST have the moment it gets released.

but if you really want to, you can keep track with the latest or even have multiple versions of php on your machine. It is possible and it wont destroy your set up, you just have to jump through a few more hoops. more info on multiple php installations [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/163407/can-i-compile-my-own-php-while-keeping-the-one-provided-with-ubuntu#163417)

Now, back to compiling php, you can go [here](http://wiki.helioviewer.org/wiki/Compiling_PHP_from_source_on_Ubuntu) for instructions. Though a bit old, they should still work. But you should also probably take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106124/updating-php-to-the-latest-version-in-ubuntu-10-04-server-edition).